# Div doesn't reload to original place after script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got a div that sticks to the top when you scroll to the top and past with it but when you scroll back to the top, it doesn't return to its original position.

https://jsfiddle.net/5ADzD/754/embedded/result/

```
function fixDiv() {
var $div = $("#navwrap");
if ($(window).scrollTop() > $div.data("top")) { 
    $('#navwrap').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'width': '100%'}); 
}
else {
    $('#navwrap').css({'position': 'absolute'});
}
}

$("#navwrap").data("top", $("#navwrap").offset().top); // set original position on load
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
```

Comment: reset function or call back function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't setting the top back to where it should be.

Try this:

```js
function fixDiv() {
  var $div = $("#navwrap");
  var top = $div.data("top");
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > top) { 
    $('#navwrap').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'width': '100%'}); 
  }
  else {
    $('#navwrap').css({'position': 'absolute', 'top' : top + 'px'}); //set back to absolute and position the top
  }
}

$("#navwrap").data("top", $("#navwrap").offset().top); // set original position on load
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
```

```css
#container {
    padding: 100px 0 2500px;
}
#navwrap{
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="navwrap">NAV WRAP</div>
</div>
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5ADzD/755/[1](https://jsfiddle.net/5ADzD/755/)

Answer (score 0):

In your `else` block, use position `relative` or `static`. That way, it returns to its original layout position.

http://jsfiddle.net/5ADzD/756/

That's because `absolute` is pretty much like `fixed`, where the element is taken out of the layout. The difference is that `fixed` stays in place and `absolute` follows (relative to the next positioned ancestor).